# How much does the Bias Voltage affect the NEP of a photodiode?

Tags: noise, datasheet, photodiode

Look at [this data sheet](https://www.hamamatsu.com/resources/pdf/ssd/s2387_series_kspd1033e.pdf) for example. Everything there is measured at 0V, including the NEP, if I connect that photodiode in reverse bias, how will that NEP change?.

I'm inclined to believe that it doesn't change, simply because whenever I read about it, no one mentions the voltage being relevant, for example in this [Thorlabs Paper](https://www.thorlabs.com/images/TabImages/Noise_Equivalent_Power_White_Paper.pdf), or in the book Optoelectronic Sensors by Decoster and Harari. (Screenshot at the end).

Then again, the NEP is measured considering all sources of noise, right?, and Dark Current grows with voltage, so it seems that NEP would change with voltage as well.

If NEP does change with voltage, how can I calculate that change?.

[image]

Comment: My 0.02, reverse bias widens the intrinsic region of a p-i-n diode. Therefore any mechanism that relies on that will increase in noise intensity.

Comment: then how do I know what is the NEP at full reverse bias?

Comment: That, unfortunately requires some work that I need to consult some sources. Reverse bias increases the "optical" gain, since the i region widens where electron hole pairs are generated, which increases SNR, which should decrease NEP. But I am not the expert.

Comment: My Grad textbook on the subject is:  Stephen A. Maas, “Noise in Linear and Nonlinear Circuits” hooe it helps.

Comment: how would the reverse bias change the spectral response of the photodiode?